# why N-Gons can subdivide some times and some times no?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, loop

as far as i know n-gons cant be subdivide by adding edge loop but i discover that some times it can be :

[image]

[image]

i tried to make loop cut again but it doesn't done ,
i know it should good thing to cut Ngons sometimes but that make me wondering /: ?!

Answer (score 5):

Going around the cube this way:

[image]

You have a continuous face loop, regardless of its ngon status, because the connecting faces just have one edge between them.

[image]

If we "unwrapped" the shape in the direction you're cutting it would look like this (I've only shown three sides)

[image]

If we went the other direction it would look something like this, with a couple extra verts:

[image]

And this is *no longer a continuous face loop*.  The *loop cut* operation will stop when it can no longer find a definite way to travel down the next face.

Looking at all the edges this cut could decide to go to:

[image]

I would say as human onlookers it's pretty clear where it *should* go, but programmatically (for the general case) it's probably a hard problem to solve.  The operation just stops when it can't find the next face in the loop.

Comment: I opened Blender just to prove you wrong, and then was surprised it actually works! :) Cool.

Comment: I dont think its because the loop cut can not continue, as such. But basically because if you subdivide the surface it does not form a strictly defined loop. Which is what 3d artist are generally looking for with a loop split. So while you could relatively easily make a inference un these cases, its just that its counter to what the modelers are generally doing. So its mainly because its preferable to terminate like this because it represents the path of least surprises few operations down the line.